# .NET Core (.NET 5) HandleChallengeAsync in custom authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, security, authentication, .net-5

I'm trying to write a custom authentication handler in a .NET 5 web app. The problem I'm unable to solve is how to handle redirection in *HandleChallengeAsync*. I see there's a *RedirectUri* property in the *AuthenticationProperties* parameter, but I don't know how and where to set it up, and once the value is set, do I need to issue a command to redirect to login URL or will it happen when calling base *HandleChallengeAsync* method?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication("TeamAuth")
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, NewTeamAuthHandler>("TeamAuth", null);
    
    // ...
}
```

handler code

```
public class NewTeamAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public NewTeamAuthHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("authentication faiure");
    }

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        // probable location of the redirection command
        await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);
    }

    protected override async Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marko, what is your authentication schema? And have you tried to set `properties.RedirectUri` 
 in `HandleChallengeAsync` method?

Comment: "TeamAuth" is the schema name, it is a custom schema. Changing properties.RedirectUri has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but if you look at the definition of the base HandleChallengeAsync method, you will see it is only:

```
protected virtual Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
   Response.StatusCode = 401;
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

So, I just made my override like this:

```
protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
   Response.Redirect("/token");
    
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Now on challenge, the user is redirected to the /token page. This works in AspNet Core 6.